# XSLT sort Alphabetically then Numerically

Tags: sorting, xslt, numerical, alphabetical

By default xslt sorts numerically then alphabetically.
What if I want alphabetically first then numerically.

```
<root>
  <item>B3</item>
  <item>A1</item>
  <item>C2</item>
  <item>3B</item>
  <item>2C</item>
  <item>1A</item>
</root>
```

I'd want:

```
<root>
  <item>A1</item>
  <item>B3</item>
  <item>C2</item>
  <item>1A</item>
  <item>2C</item>
  <item>3B</item>
</root>
```

The thing is I don't know how long or how many letters numbers are in the names. It could be 1054-FS or C104-G. Also C20-H should comme before C101-H.

Is that something easy to achieve without knowledge of what will be pushed through ?

Thanks.

Comment: The rules are not quite clear.

Comment: `What if I want alphabetically first then numerically` and `C20-H should comme before C101-H` are in contrast.

Comment: I can just about see how this is doable in XSLT 2.0, is that an option or are you limited to 1.0? And if 1.0, which processor are you using?

Comment: @IanRoberts I'm learning through this process so a solution in XSLT2.0 should be welcome. As for processing I'm currently using the default processor of google chrome, and after searching I found that it uses libxslt library. Michael Kay (below) rephrased what I need and he's way clearer then I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are saying is that you want a collation sequence in which letters precede digits.

If you want C20 to precede C101 then you are also looking for a collation that groups consecutive digits and sorts them as numbers.

It's incorrect to say that XSLT (always) sorts digits before letters. The default collation depends on the XSLT processor you are using, it's not defined in the language specification.

In XSLT 3.0, and in Saxon 9.6, you can use the Unicode Collation Algorithm to achieve this effect. You would write

```
<xsl:sort select="..." 
collation="http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?numeric=yes;reorder=Latn,digit"/>
```

(I haven't tested this specific example).

If you're using some other processor, you'll have to check its documentation to see what collation options it provides. You can sometimes play tricks for example by using `<xsl:sort select="translate(....)"/>` to compute a sort key that works the way you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to ask.  I'm fairly new to XSLT and trying to puts information taken here and there together to achieve what I want... probably not the best way to learn though.

I'm processing my XML with XSL through Google Chrome default processor which I don't even know which it is.

Comment: The XSLT processors available in the browser are all pretty basic XSLT 1.0 processors, haven't been upgraded for years.

Comment: with XSLT 1.0, I would implement "letters before numbers" by using translate() to translate digits 0-9 into something higher up the Unicode scale, e.g. Arabic Indic digits; and I would probably give up on "consecutive digits" unless it's absolutely imperative.